# New line error in c++

Tags: c++, delimiter, getline

I am trying to define the delimiter character in the getline() function in C++ as you can see below:

```
getline(fin, title, '\r\n');
```

The problem is it is taking it in as an ASCII `int` value instead of a `char` value.  How would I get it to recognize it as a `char` so it would go to the new line in the file?

Comment: these are two characters but getline takes only one

Comment: Using single quotes is only for single characters. You have two: '\r' and '\n'.

Comment: I am trying to read a file in line by line into separate strings but the first get line reads the whole file into one string.  I thought I needed to define the delimiter as a third argument in getline but neither works separately.

Answer (score 1):

Simply read it as

```
getline(fin, title, '\n');
```

and then remove '\r' if it is present in the string. For example

```
if ( !title.empty() && title.back() == '\r' ) title.erase( title.size() - 1 );
```

As for character literal '\r\n' then in any case there is no sense to compare it with a character in the input buffer. In any case they will be unequal.